# Facebook Like button Comment Box alignment changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, cross-domain, alignment

I'm attempting to influence the layout of the Facebook like button in relation to the comment box that appears after clicking like. There is **most definitely** a mechanism built-in to the the Facebook JS (I'm seeing `_repositionIframe`) however I cannot figure out what precisely triggers this behavior - the like button is floated to the right inside the iFrame, and the iFrame itself is offset to the left, making the comment box aligned with the right side of the like button without changing the position of the like button.

I stumbled across this behavior after wrapping my Like button with a `div` with the following CSS:

```css
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
```

This causes Chrome and IE8/9 to display the comment box the way I want:

[image]

However, Firefox and Safari are displaying it as the default left alignment:
[image: Left Align]

The nature of the project does not allow me to disclose much about it, and it's being developed on a private network. I will answer any specific questions I can.

Thanks!